# Display message after file download in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, download

I have the following JSP code to download a file:

```
                        // reads input file from an absolute path
                        File downloadFile = new File(fullPath);
                        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);


                        // obtains ServletContext
                        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

                        // gets MIME type of the file
                        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);
                        if (mimeType == null) {        
                            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
                            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                        }
                        out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);
                        // modifies response
                        response.setContentType(mimeType);
                        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

                        // forces download
                        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
                        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                        // obtains response's output stream
                        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int bytesRead = -1;

                        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }

                        inStream.close();
                        outStream.close(); 
                        out.println("<strong>" + sqlResults[1] + "</strong> records exported from " + fileType + " table.<br>");
```

When I run this code, I get a pop-up that let's me select the destination directory.  When I click OK, the file downloads and the browser immediately returns to the previous screen (that is, the screen that called this JSP code).

The browser does not display:

```
out.println("<strong>" + sqlResults[1] + "</strong> records exported from " + fileType + " table.<br>");
```

My question is: How do I correct the code to display this message in the browser immediately after the file downloads?

Comment: is all this part of a form tag?? i mean inside a form tag?

Comment: No.  There is a form action after this code, but it is a submit button that allows user to go back to home page after the file download is completed.  All of this is ignored once file is actually downloaded, and user is immediately returned to previous screen.